# Trying to access array offset on value of type null in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

I am getting this error when I am trying to create a new object

```
$provider = new ExpressCheckout;
$response = $provider->setExpressCheckout($checkoutData);
```

I am using this package https://github.com/srmklive/laravel-paypal
to integrate the PayPal ExpressCheckout in my Laravel app

**Error Message**

> ErrorException Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Comment: please provide the error message so that others may be able to answer the question

Comment: @Dhiraj Yes I have updated the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should clear the cache. Run these commands

```
composer update 

php artisan cache:clear 
php artisan config:clear 
php artisan view:clear
```

Answer (score 1):

`$provider = new PayPalClient([]);`

Use empty array for the construct.